# jQuery filter for multiple classes, on match, hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple `divs` of class `.item`.
On click at the **Classfilter**-submit button all `.item`-elements, which have also at least one class stored in the `dateClasses`-Array (e.g. ['28.09.2015', '29.09.2015']), should get hidden.

To recap the elements with the green border should get hidden, when the users clicks on the button.

**Important:** The `dateClasses`-array values may change dynamically. And I have to check against an array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   classFilter();
 });


 function classFilter() {
   $('#filter').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var dateClasses = ['28.09.2015', '29.09.2015']; //Hide the item-div if one these classes is applied

     $('.item').filter(function() {
       $(this).hasClasses(dateClasses)
     }).addClass('hide-event');
   });
 }

 $.fn.extend({
   hasClasses: function(selectors) {
     var self = this;
     for (var i in selectors) {
       console.log($(self).hasClass(selectors[i]));
       if ($(self).hasClass(selectors[i])) {
         return true;
       }
     }
     return false;
   }
 });
```

```css
.hide-event {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item 28.09.2015" style="border: 10px solid green">
  Hide this if class is in array</div>
<div class="item 29.09.2015" style="border: 10px solid green">
  Hide this if class is in array</div>
<div class="item 30.09.2015" style="border: 10px solid blue">
  Hide this if class is in array</div>
<input type="submit" name="filter" value="Classfilter" id="filter">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NOTE: You can't use `dot` in a classname and should parse those names to use another character like `-` or `_` before they get put into the dom

You are not returning anything inside `filter()`

To fix the filter :

```
$('.item').filter(function() {
     return  $(this).hasClasses(dateClasses);
}).addClass('hide-event');
```

There are likely simpler approaches to achieve what you want but this is the root problem of the code shown without rewriting your plugin

One very simple approach would be:

```
$('.item').filter('.' + dateClasses.join(',.')).addClass('hide-event');
```

[Demo with valid class names](http://jsfiddle.net/9h5435gf/)

Comment: Thanks, both versions work like a charm. Do you know which implementation is faster?

Comment: you would need to create a perf test to determine the faster one